# Unhandled Exception: System.IndexOutOfRangeException

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

I am trying to connect my code to a SQL Server database and see my data in console window but I can't do so as I am getting an exception which says:

> Unhandled Exception: System.IndexOutOfRangeException: userPassword.

I have tried a number of solutions found on the web but none is working for me. I am a beginner at SQL Server so may be I am missing something obvious.

This is my `app.config` file:

```
<configuration>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="provider" value="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
        <add key="connectionString" 
             value="Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Tayyab\Documents\myDatabase.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30"/>
    </appSettings>

    <startup>
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1" />
    </startup>
</configuration>
```

and my `Program.cs` file contains:

```
namespace _6_11_2018
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //working with database
            string provider = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["provider"];
            string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["connectionString"];
            DbProviderFactory factory = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(provider);

            using (DbConnection connection = factory.CreateConnection())
            {
                if(connection == null)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Connnection Error");
                    Console.ReadLine();
                    return;
                }

                connection.ConnectionString = connectionString;

                connection.Open();

                DbCommand command = factory.CreateCommand();

                if (command == null)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("command Error");
                    Console.ReadLine();
                    return;
                }

                command.Connection = connection;

                command.CommandText = "Select * From userPassword";

                using (DbDataReader dataReader = command.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (dataReader.Read())
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine($"{dataReader["User"]} "
                            + $"{dataReader["userPassword"]}");
                    }
                }

                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Try to change `connecttionString` to `connectionString` (just one `t`).

Comment: hi so not related to your question but just a suggestion: the namespace should be something useful rather than a date it might benefit you to use a good name... it’s a library after all :)

Comment: thanks @stickybit for your help as this little change has removed the above exception but there is another one

Comment: Thanks @mad.meesh for your suggestion

Comment: Current Exception is showing that:
Unhandled Exception: System.IndexOutOfRangeException: userPassword
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.FieldNameLookup.GetOrdinal(String fieldName)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.GetOrdinal(String name)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_Item(String name)
   at _6_11_2018.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\Tayyab\source\repos\6-11-2018\6-11-2018\Program.cs:line 48

Comment: can you list the column on table userPassword in DB?

Comment: There are two columns in my userPassword table: User & Password
@AdinugrahaTawaqal

Comment: but you select User and userPassword

Comment: Console.WriteLine($"{dataReader["User"]} "
                            + $"{dataReader["userPassword"]}");

Answer (score 0):

you select `User` and `userPassword`

```
Console.WriteLine($"{dataReader["User"]} " + $"{dataReader["userPassword"]}");
```

But there are no `userPassword` columns on userPassword table. Columns in userPassword table are User & Password.